# Assigning pointer to pointer does not make them equal

Tags: c++, pointers, hashmap

I have a big static hashmap of descriptions of unicode codepoints. Each hash value leads to an null-terminated array of pointers to the elements. The following is my access function:

```
extern CodepointInfo ***codepoint_table;

uint32_t fnv1a(uint32_t input) { ... } // hash function

const CodepointInfo CodepointInfo::get(uint32_t codepoint) {
    uint32_t hash = fnv1a(codepoint) % 30000 // Number of buckets of the hashmap
    CodepointInfo **bucket = codepoint_table[hash];
    for(uint32_t i = 0; bucket[i] != nullptr; i++) {
            if(bucket[i]->codepoint == codepoint)
                    return *(codepoint_table[hash][i]);
    }
    return {codepoint, "unassigned", GeneralCategory::UNASSIGNED, 0, BidiClass::L, DecompositionType::NONE, nullptr, -1, nullptr, false, 0, 0, 0};
}
```

Now when I tried using it, I encountered a segfault so I started debugging it with gdb and got the following output:

```
Breakpoint 1, nsucs::CodepointInfo::get (codepoint=0) at /home/richard/src/libnsucs/lib/codepoint_info.cc:21
21      uint32_t hash = fnv1a(codepoint) % NSUCS_CODEPOINTTABLE_NUM_BUCKETS;
(gdb) n
22      CodepointInfo **bucket = codepoint_table[hash];
(gdb) n
23      for(uint32_t i = 0; bucket[i] != nullptr; i++) {
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff78cbd44 in nsucs::CodepointInfo::get (codepoint=0) at /home/richard/src/libnsucs/lib/codepoint_info.cc:23
23      for(uint32_t i = 0; bucket[i] != nullptr; i++) {
(gdb) print hash
$1 = 18805
(gdb) print codepoint_table[hash]
$2 = (nsucs::CodepointInfo **) 0x7ffff7d61d00 <nsucs::codepoint_table_fragment_18805>
(gdb) print bucket
$3 = (nsucs::CodepointInfo **) 0x0
```

Shouldn't `codepoint_table[hash]` and `bucket` be equal after assigning one to the other? When I replace the usage of `bucket` by `codepoint_table[hash]` it still segfaults but `print codepoint_table[hash][i]` in gdb yields the correct result.

What is happening here? The binaries are not optimized at all.

EDIT:

The definition of the CodepointInfo struct:

```
struct CodepointInfo {
    static const CodepointInfo get(uint32_t codepoint);

    uint32_t codepoint;
    const char *name;
    uint32_t general_category;
    uint8_t canonical_combining_class;
    BidiClass::Enum bidi_class;
    DecompositionType::Enum decomposition_type;
    uint32_t *decomposition_mapping;
    int8_t decimal_value;
    const char *numeric_value;
    bool bidi_mirrored;
    uint32_t simple_uppercase_mapping;
    uint32_t simple_lowercase_mapping;
    uint32_t simple_titlecase_mapping;
};
```

Comment: CodepointInfo has some assign operator overload?

Comment: Nope no operator overload at all. I'll add the definition to the question.

Comment: You're never changing the `bucket`, right? If so, declare it as `CodepointInfo ** const`

Comment: Also, `assert(nullptr!=codepoint_table[hash])` before the assignment.

Comment: a wide shot: is there some other code that might change `codepoint_table` in another thread?

Comment: Adding const doesn't change the result.

Comment: Fixed the error. Answer coming...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing `extern CodepointInfo ***codepoint_table;` to `extern CodepointInfo **codepoint_table[];` which matches the declaration in the external compilation unit.

Still don't have any idea why this lead to the wrong assignment behaviour.